# Register services in Consul with azure app services?

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, consul, service-discovery

I'm having trouble to register correctly micro-services with Consul. Here how it goes : I have 3 micro-services written in asp.net core. These 3 services are deployed in 3 app services on azure (each of them has an URL associated). When I run these services I register them in a consul server running in a container instance on azure. I register them with the URL (the services are visible in the consul console), but when I do this, the port 0 is associated with it by default and when I try to call these services via the Api-Gateway it seems like the api-gateway does not find the service since the url is map to the port 0.

Here how a registered service looks : [image]

Is there a possibility to remove the port or I'm maybe doing it the wrong way (maybe it's not even possible to do it that way)?

PS: Everything works local, when my microservices are registered via localhost+port mapping, the api calls are achieved correctly. But when I try to register them without port and only with an adress (URL azure), it does not work anymore.

Thanks in advance for those who'll read or try to help,

Lio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I should wait 1 more hour or 2 before posting here, I managed to find the solution, instead of not specifying any port, I specified port 443 for https, and now it works.